# I am working on angular 5 form validation, my requirement is when i click submit that time validation should work not on ngtouch

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms, angular5, angular4-forms

I am working on angular 5 form validation, my requirement is when I click  submit that time validation should work not on ng-touch

Comment: Please show us what you have done till now

Answer (score 0):

If you have angular 5+ then you can use the new updateOn property:

Something like this:

```
this.login = new FormGroup({
   email: new FormControl(),
   password: new FormControl()
}, { updateOn: 'submit' });
```

Angular 5 now gives you options to do validations on events such as blur of a control, or submit of a form using this property.

Read [here](https://netbasal.com/boosting-performance-with-the-new-updateon-option-in-angular-v5-18857279ace2)

If you want a different behavior for one particular field(In the below example:email), you can do something like this:

```
this.login = new FormGroup({
   email: new FormControl(null, {
      validators: Validators.required,
      updateOn: 'blur'
   }),
   password: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required])
}, {updateOn: 'submit'})
```

Comment: already I tried but it not working. normally when I click input field that time validation is working but my requirement is when I click submit that time validation should be work

Comment: Make sure you have Angular 5+. What is the version of Angular?

Comment: @deezg yes sorry my bad

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Angular2/4, then you can try this

in your component

```
 submitted: boolean = false;
 ngOnInit() {
  this.myForm = new FormGroup({
    name: new FormControl('', [<any>Validators.minLength(5)]),
  });
 }
save(){
  this.submitted =true;
  if(this.myForm.invalid){
   return;
 }
 // Here write your code for processing
}
```

In your template

```
 <form [formGroup]="myForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="save()">
  <label>Name</label>
  <input type="text" formControlName="name">
  <small *ngIf="!myForm.controls.name.valid && submitted">
     Enter minimum 5 characters for name.
  </small>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```